# Is it possible to generate QR Codes on a flutter app with a logo or saying in the middle. How would one go about this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-qrcode

Currently trying to build a custom QR code generator that would either include a logo or some text in the middle so it is not generic have been scouring the internet looking for solutions but mainly see general texts on how to generate a QR code using flutter.

I understand you can make a simple version of this with a pub package but how would you make your own with a logo. Sorry if this question has already been answered I am a beginner, but it doesn't seem that answers on here exactly answer this question. :)

Comment: can you share any answer that you saw?

Comment: @Nguyenfamily Here's one that I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249844/flutter-web-how-to-create-a-flutter-web-app-which-opens-when-a-qr-code-is-scann